# Circuit analysis with a dependent current source

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have been working through Boylestad and I am having trouble with this folling question.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQARLH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

h = 50.

this one i'm finding difficult because the current source depends on another part of this network.
I tried applying Kirchhoff's law around the both loops to get loop currents \$I_1\$ and \$I_2\$.
$$hI = I_1 - I_2$$

So \$I = I_1\$

Then I got $$hI_1 = I_1 - I_2$$

$$0 = I_1(1-h) - I_2$$

And I used kirchhoff's around the outer loop to get the second equations.
$$20 = I_1(2000) + I_2(2000)$$

So I used these two equations using determinants but I didn't get the result in the book which was \$19.62\angle 53^\circ\$

Am I on the right path here or is there a better way to try and get the correct answer?

Now correctly completed with the help of @TimWescott and @relayman357 with the correct equations:
$$I_1(1+h)-I_2=0$$
$$I_1(2000) + I_2(2000) = 20\angle 53^\circ$$

Then using determinant to determine \$I_2\$ to then find \$VR2\$.

Comment: For \$I = +I_1\$ to be true, \$I_1\$ needs to be in the direction of \$I\$.  For \$hI_1 = I_1 - I_2\$ to be true, \$I_1\$ needs to be *opposite* the direction of \$I\$.  This is super easy to get wrong -- do your numbers again?  It never hurts to actually draw in the loop currents.

Comment: True @TimWescott thanks. I will investigate in ciruitlab if you can put in loop currents.

Comment: Your KVL equation assumes \$i_1\$ is referenced (arrow direction) going to right, but your equation, \$I=I_1\$ assumes the opposite.

Comment: Note that there really is only one loop here.

Answer (score 1):

Your nodal equation is wrong if i'm understanding the directions you assumed for your loop currents.  If my figure below is correct, then your KCL should give,

$$i_1 + hi_1 = i_2$$
$$(h+1)i_1 - i_2 = 0$$

[image]

You can also try writing a single KVL equation around the entire perimeter - and recognize that the current going up through R2 is \$(h+1)I\$.

Comment: Oh yeah just put in loop currents like that, yep, I get it now. Correct, the diagram was correct I forgot to take into account the opposite direction. My loop currents I had going clockwise, but I wrote them down wrong in here. I meant \$I = -I_1\$.

Comment: Good deal.  Easy mistake to make when you don't take time to label things well.

Comment: Where I went wrong in my calculations but correct in writing it down here was actually in my second equation. I had \$20\angle 53^\circ = I_1(2000) - I_2(2000)/$ which is wrong. So let me go back and use what you have shown me here and see if I can get the result. Thanks. @relayman357

Comment: Also, that answer you show in your question, \$19.62\angle53⁰\$, is questionable if that was for the voltage across R2.

Comment: Really? So you think the book could be wrong? I was thinking that because I thought that the current from \$hI\$ would be travelling up the \$R2\$ branch in the opposite direction of the current down that branch from the voltage source, therefore reducing the voltage. Let me go and do some sums.

Comment: Yes, not much way around the fact that \$(h+1)I\$ flows up through R2.  Problems in some books are poked in by graduate students - who are sometimes asleep at the wheel.

Comment: Yeah that worked. I think I realise why it's such a high voltage. \$hI\$ is actually going in reverse isn't it, thus summing with the current from the voltage as it goes down \$R2 \$ branch.

Comment: Can you have a current source going negative (i.e. sending current the opposite direction to which it is labeled)? Or does that not make sense @relayman357 ?

Comment: It will produce whatever voltage (magnitude and polarity) necessary to produce it’s controlled current, \$hI\$.

Answer (score 1):

The current through R2 is \$(1+h)I\$, so the loop gives
\$v(t) = I R_1 + (1+h) I R_2 \$ and so
\$ I = {v(t) \over R_1 + (1+h) R_2 } \$, and
\$v_{R_2}(t) =  {(1+h)R_2\  v(t) \over R_1 + (1+h) R_2 } \$.

Substituting \$h=50, R_1=R_2 = 2k \$ gives \$v_{R_2} \approx 19.6 \angle 53^\circ\$RMS.

Comment: That's really good @copper.hat . Much more succinct than the way i did it.